# Увеличение фото во весь экран без окон и рамки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет, заранее извиняюсь за пример с сайта для взрослых, но нигде больше подобного не видел.

Пример на сайте xuk.net(для взрослых сайт). На сайте при нажатии на лупу изображение становится больше размера окна и по нему можно перемещаться курсором, оно ездит вверх или вниз или вбока, тем самым перемещая увеличенную область изображения во все окно.

Как реализовать такое увеличение или как содрать скрипт? Все спрятано похоже и зашифровано.

Answer (score 3):

Если не особо вдаваться в нюансы, то [вот примитивный пример](https://jsfiddle.net/wnfcjvvm/):

```js
$('.preview').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('fullsize').find('img').attr('style', '');
});

$(document).on('mousemove', '.fullsize', function(e) {
  var img = $('img', this),
    docW = $(document).width(),
    docH = $(document).height(),
    factorX = (img.width() - docW) / docW,
    factorY = (img.height() - docH) / docH;
  img.css({
    marginLeft: -(e.pageX * factorX),
    marginTop: -(e.pageY * factorY)
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.preview {
  width: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.preview img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.fullsize {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100500;
}
.preview.fullsize img {
  max-width: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preview">
  <img src="http://www.sunhome.ru/UsersGallery/wallpapers/20/4142919.jpg" alt="">
</div>

<div class="preview">
  <img src="http://ru-wallp.com/w/2010/1/13/873884-wp-1245737192208.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: А если развернуть пример на всю страницу?

Comment: @Other, делать простую проверку: если изображение меньше или равно размеру экрана, то действия не выполнять.

Comment: Все отлично, но в примере не учтен момент, если размер HTML больше, чем размер изображения, то x и y рассчитываются не верно. Какую формулу использовать, что бы учесть это?

Comment: @Барин, никакую формулу, в этом случае, уже не использовать и об этом я написал еще вчера. Смотрите комментарий перед своим.

Comment: @Deonis, вот я на вашем примере сделал, увеличил страницу в высоту. https://jsfiddle.net/guxd9847/1/ Теперь нажмите на увеличение и поймете, что по изображению уже не верно перемещается, координаты съехали.

Comment: @Барин, я вас прекрасно понял, а вот вы, похоже, меня - нет. В первом комментарии, Other уже намекнул на то, что вы сейчас изложили и я ему ответил. Попробую разжевать более подробно: если изображение меньше размеров видимой области экрана (viewport), то  смещение изображения не применяем, а только увеличиваем. Если же только один из размеров меньше, то именно эту ось не трогаем. Какой алгоритм тут применить - зависит от вашей фантазии. Можно проверять на этапе увеличения или же во время движения мыши, а можно [сделать  таким образом](https://jsfiddle.net/wnfcjvvm/1/)

Comment: @Deonis, так это увеличение, нужно увеличивать фото не в зависимости от того, какого оно размера. Если фото меньше - его нужно растягивать по ширине на ширину экрана, а по высоте - увеличивается пропорционально и появляется возможность движения мышкой, как и в примере на сайте. А у вас не увеличивается и не двигается, если размер меньше экрана у изображения. Правильно работает только если в топ прокручивать перед отображением, но работает глючно, как я указал в своем нижнем сообщении отдельном.

Comment: @Барин вы ждёте идеальное и готовое решение? Уж простите, но у меня нет желания тратить время на человека, который совсем не хочет прилагать своих усилий. Даю вам тонкий намёк и на этом закончим: для увеличенного изображения задаём `min-width: 100vw;`

Comment: Я не жду идеального и готового изображения и тем более я не из тех, кто совсем не хочет прилагать своих усилий! Как я уже сказал, повторюсь, я пофиксил этот баг внизу вторым сообщением своим. про 100vw я даже не в курсе, я не программист, я лишь кодер, который с помощью гугла что-то пытается писать, мне нужна наводка, за нее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

В случае, если HTML больше окна, то глюки возникают с прокруткой. Какую формулу можно сделать, что бы не было таких проблем?

Я данный баг пофиксил с помощью скролла, на 0 откручиваю вверх картинку, а после закрытия ее возвращаю предыдущий scrollTop, но это все не очень надежно(

```
 $('.zoomer').on('click', function() {

 $(this).toggleClass('fullsize').find('img').attr('style', '');



 if (scroll>0) {$(window).scrollTop(scroll); scroll=0; }

 else { scroll=$(window).scrollTop(); }



 });



 $(document).on('mousemove', '.fullsize', function(e) {


 var img = $('img', this),

   docW = document.documentElement.clientWidth,

  docH = document.documentElement.clientHeight,

  factorX = (img.width() - docW) / docW,

   factorY = (img.height() - docH) / docH;


 $(window).scrollTop(0);


  img.css({

   marginLeft: -(e.pageX * factorX),

   marginTop: -(e.pageY * factorY)

  });


 });
```